# GetPositionAtOffset equivalent for text only?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox

Is there a **pretty** solution of a `GetPositionAtOffset()` equivalent which only counts text insertion positions instead of all symbols?

Motivation example in C#:

```cs
TextRange GetRange(RichTextBox rtb, int startIndex, int length) {
    TextPointer startPointer = rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(startIndex);
    TextPointer endPointer = startPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(length);
    return new TextRange(startPointer, endPointer);
}
```

Edit: Until now i "solved" it this way

```cs
public static TextPointer GetInsertionPositionAtOffset(this TextPointer position, int offset, LogicalDirection direction)
{
    if (!position.IsAtInsertionPosition) position = position.GetNextInsertionPosition(direction);
    while (offset > 0 && position != null)
    {
        position = position.GetNextInsertionPosition(direction);
        offset--;
        if (Environment.NewLine.Length == 2 && position != null && position.IsAtLineStartPosition) offset --; 
    }
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Wow someone REALLY didn't want the RichTextBox to be used.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't. My suggestion is that you create your own GetPositionAtOffset method for this purpose. You can check which PointerContext the TextPointer is adjacent to by using:

```
TextPointer.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection);
```

To get the next TextPointer which points to a different PointerContext:

```
TextPointer.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection);
```

Some sample code I used in a recent project, this makes sure that the pointer context is of type Text, by looping until one is found. You could use this in your implementation and skip an offset increment if it is found:

```
// for a TextPointer start

while (start.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) 
                             != TextPointerContext.Text)
{
    start = start.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    if (start == null) return;
}
```

Hopefully you can make use of this information.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know TextPointerContext until now :)

Comment: Glad to help. Let me know if you need anything else! Good hunting.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find effective solution to this problem for a long time. 
Next piece of code works in my case with the highest performance. Hope it will help somebody as well.

```
TextPointer startPos = rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(searchWordIndex, LogicalDirection.Forward);
startPos = startPos.CorrectPosition(searchWord, FindDialog.IsCaseSensitive);
if (startPos != null)
{
    TextPointer endPos = startPos.GetPositionAtOffset(textLength, LogicalDirection.Forward);
    if (endPos != null)
    {
         rtb.Selection.Select(startPos, endPos);
    }
}

public static TextPointer CorrectPosition(this TextPointer position, string word, bool caseSensitive)
{
   TextPointer start = null;
   while (position != null)
   {
       if (position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
       {
           string textRun = position.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);

           int indexInRun = textRun.IndexOf(word, caseSensitive ? StringComparison.InvariantCulture : StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
           if (indexInRun >= 0)
           {
               start = position.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun);
               break;
           }
       }

       position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
   }

   return start; }
```