# How To Set Caret Position At The End Of Current Line In A RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm trying to place the caret of a `RichTextBox` at the end of the current line it's in. The `.CaretPosition` attribute is a big change from just using the simple `.CaretIndex` attribute of a regular `TextBox`.

To tackle this issue, I've made my own User-Control which is just a `RichTextBox` that has most of the properties/methods a `TextBox` has, such as `.LineCount`, `.Text`, `.CaretIndex`, etc. I made a `CaretIndex { get; set; }` property within my User-Control that looks like this:

```
public int CaretIndex
        {
            get
            {
                TextPointer start = display.Document.ContentStart;
                TextPointer curPosition = display.CaretPosition;
                TextRange range = new TextRange(start, curPosition);
                return range.Text.Length;
            }
            set
            {
                display.CaretPosition = display.Document.ContentStart;
                for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
                {
                    TextPointer move = display.CaretPosition.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    if (move != null)
                        display.CaretPosition = move;
                }
            }
        }
```

The `get` method seems to work fine, but `set` doesn't do what I envision it to accomplish. My goal was to have the caret move logically forward a "value" amount of times - value being how many characters I want to move past - but the result is just abstract caret placement behavior. The caret could either get placed a couple lines down, right below the original line, or all the way to the bottom of the `RichTextBox`.

All I want is an easy way to move the caret left or right without undefined behavior. Am I approaching my `CaretIndex` property the wrong way? Do I have a false perception of the `CaretPosition` property of a `RichTextBox`? Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: You might want to try `display.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(CaretIndex, LogicalDirection.Forward);` https://stackoverflow.com/a/18653876/5308388

Comment: @Riddell Does it need to be in a loop or just that one liner?

Comment: @Riddell That doesn't work either, it just returns null

Answer (score 0):

I made a small wpf app to test your code -

xaml -

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<RichTextBox Grid.Row="0" Name="Rtb" />
<Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Get" Click="Button_Get" />

<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Set" Click="Button_Set" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="DesiredPositionBox" />
</Grid>
```

c# -

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Rtb.AppendText("lineoftextlineoftextlineoftextlineoftext");
        Rtb.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        Rtb.AppendText("lineoftextlineoftextlineoftextlineoftext");
    }

    private void Button_Get(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextPointer start = Rtb.Document.ContentStart;
        TextPointer curPosition = Rtb.CaretPosition;
        TextRange range = new TextRange(start, curPosition);
        Debug.WriteLine("Caret position : " + range.Text.Length);

        Rtb.Focus();
    }

    private void Button_Set(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int value = int.Parse(DesiredPositionBox.Text);

        Rtb.CaretPosition = Rtb.Document.ContentStart;
        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
        {
            TextPointer move = Rtb.CaretPosition.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            if (move != null)
                Rtb.CaretPosition = move;
        }

        Rtb.Focus();
    }
```

The line `Rtb.CaretPosition = Rtb.Document.ContentStart;` moves the caret to the start every time, so if you pass in '5' the caret will be moved to the 5th character from the start of the RichTextBox.

Remove `Rtb.CaretPosition = Rtb.Document.ContentStart;` and the caret will move `x` positions from where it was.

edit:
To also answer how to place the caret at the end of the line,
you can use `Rtb.CaretPosition.GetTextRunLength(LogicalDirection.Forward)` to get
the number of characters, counting from the caret, before the first non text symbol ( which line break happens to be ).

So -

```
        int value = Rtb.CaretPosition.GetTextRunLength(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        TextPointer move = Rtb.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(value);
        Rtb.CaretPosition = move;
```

Comment: That would work assuming all the text you want in the rich text box has already been added. If you're adding text and trying to move the caret at the same time, the rich text box will act as if it's contents are from prior the text input. Also the whole "\r\n" thing the rich text box automatically inputs is super annoying, I think that's what puts the caret at the bottom of the rich text box

Comment: The question you posed was "How To Set Caret Position At The End Of Current Line In A RichTextBox" in the topic, and noted "My goal was to have the caret move logically forward a "value" amount of times" in the question. Could edit your question to further clarify what you are looking for exactly, as the code I posted answers those two issues. Also you probably need to update the caret position after inserting text ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/39990299/10835140 ).